# How to translate country names / a generic array in twig or controller in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, translation, twig, icu

I have an array filled with all countries name and I want to translate this names but I don't know how

In my controller I did:

```
$countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", ....);

return $this->render('xBundle:x:xs.html.twig', array('countries' => json_encode($countries))
```

And in my template I have:

```
List : {{countries}}
```

Comment: Please don't use pseudo-tags in titles.

Comment: Why would you json encode your view parameters ? What's wrong with giving directly the countries `array('countries' => $countries)` ?

Comment: ok but how can I translate them?

Comment: did you already add the translations to your application and you just need to know how to use the twig translation filter?

Comment: Actually evrything is ready but I don't know how to translate an array, I know how only when it is a string but array no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since symfony 2.3 country names can be translated using Intl and the [RegionBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html#country-names).

The default returned array of `getCountryNames()` looks like this:

> => array('AF' => 'Afghanistan', ...)

If you're only interested in the country names use something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

// get all country names in locale "locale"
$countries = array_values(Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames('de'));

// get all country names for current locale
$countries = array_values(Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames());
```

... in case you just want to translate an array using the translator.

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');

foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {
    $countries[$key] = $translator->trans($country, array(), null, 'de');
}
```

See the [Translator API Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html) and read the [cookbook chapter Translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#basic-translation).